# Camera overlay with flex mobile

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, camera, flash-builder

I would like if it possible to have a mask overlay over the camera using flex mobile framework. I need to develop a cross platform (android/iOS) application using camera on which I want to display buildings. So I know it is possible with native iOS and android code. But I would like to do it with flex mobile.

Do you know if it only possible or not ?

Thansk a lot.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Using Adobe Air's camera class, you cannot manipulate the picture this way.
You can change quality, sizing, frame rate etc., but cannot manipulate the image so it will show additional data except data received from the device.